# Pk fields always ends up in resulting query GROUP BY clause

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm, postgresql-9.3

I have my model hierarchy defined as follows:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    discount_price = models.DecimalField(blank=False, null=False, decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
    normal_price = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
    available_count = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    buyer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=False)
    buyer_email = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    pickup_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    taken = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=False)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=1)
```

I'm trying to get some statistics about orders and I came up with django orm call that looks like this:

```
queryset.filter(created_at__range=[date_start, date_end])\
        .annotate(price=Sum(F('items__meal__discount_price') * F('items__amount'), output_field=DecimalField()))
        .annotate(created_at_date=TruncDate('created_at'))\
        .annotate(amount=Sum('items__amount'))\
        .values('created_at_date', 'price', 'amount')
```

The above however doesn't give me the expected results, because for some reason the `id` column still ends up in the `GROUP BY` clause of sql query. Any help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work I had to do the following:

```
qs.filter(created_at__range=[date_start, date_end])\
  .annotate(created_at_date=TruncDate('created_at'))\
  .values('created_at_date')\
  .annotate(price=Sum(F('items__meal__discount_price') * F('items__amount'), 
                        output_field=DecimalField()))
  .annotate(amount=Sum('items__amount'))
```

Which kind of makes sense - I pull only the `created_at` field, transform it and then annotate the result with two other fields.